# In NS-3, How to do you assign node id and how to retrive/display them in the terminal?

Tags: node.js, network-programming, ns2, ns-3

I want to display 20 nodes with its unique id. I have created 20 nodes using for loop with the following command.

```
NodeContainer c;
c.Create (20);
int j;
for(j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{   
  m.Install (c.Get(j));
}
std::count << "Node Id: %d" << ??? <<std::endl;
```

The above code created 20 nodes and seen in the simulation tool Netanim. Now I need to display each of these nodes with unique id in the terminal.

Can anyone tell me how to assign the node id?

Comment: NS-3 : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Answer (score 0):

```
 NodeContainer c;
 c.Create (20);
 for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
 {
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "node-" << i;   
 }
```

Try the above code to display each node in the terminal instead of your code. This works in my network.
Thank you.